# CoGroupByKey not giving desired results Apache Beam(python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been testing to make a join of pub/sub read data with a self created data. Below is the main pipeline method.

```
def run(input_topic,input_subscription, output_path, window_size=1.0, num_shards=5, pipeline_args=None):
    
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True)
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        # reading from pub/sub and creating a fixed window of 1 min.
        p1 =  pipeline | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)\
        | "Window into" >> GroupMessagesByFixedWindows(window_size, num_shards)
        #creating sample data 
        p2 = pipeline | "creating a sample data" >> Create([('Hello','sh 1'),('Hello','sh 1.1'),
        ('Hello_world','sh 2'),
        ('Hello_everyone','sh 3'),
        ('Hello_cloud','sh 4')])
    
        ({"schdedule":p2,"timestamp":p1}) | "merging" >> CoGroupByKey()| "merge print">> Map(print)
```

below is the window and addtimestamp transformation method.

```
class GroupMessagesByFixedWindows(PTransform):
    """A composite transform that groups Pub/Sub messages based on publish time
    and outputs a list of tuples, each containing a message and its publish time.
    """

    def __init__(self, window_size, num_shards=5):
        # Set window size to 30 seconds.
        self.window_size = int(window_size * 30)
        self.num_shards = num_shards

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            # Bind window info to each element using element timestamp (or publish time).
            | "Window into fixed intervals"
            >> WindowInto(FixedWindows(self.window_size))
            | "Add timestamp to windowed elements" >> ParDo(AddTimestamp())
                                    
        )


class AddTimestamp(DoFn):
    def process(self, element, publish_time=DoFn.TimestampParam, window=DoFn.WindowParam):
        """Processes each windowed element by extracting the message body and its
        publish time into a tuple.
        """
        yield (element.decode("utf-8"),datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(publish_time)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

the results I am getting is shown below.

```
('Hello', {'schdedule': [], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
('Hello_world', {'schdedule': [], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
('Hello_everyone', {'schdedule': [], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
```

the **schedule** list printed empty because it is not joining.

expectation is

```
('Hello', {'schdedule': ['sh 1','sh 1.1'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
('Hello_world', {'schdedule': ['sh 2'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
('Hello_everyone', {'schdedule': ['sh 3'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
```

I tried doing **GroupByKey** seperately on p2 and it worked fine and gave me below results.

```
('Hello', ['sh 1','sh 1.1'])
('Hello_world', ['sh 2'])
('Hello_everyone', ['sh 3'])
```

Also tried static dictionary with side inputs and it worked fine but once I do **CoGroupByKey** it is not yielding any result from p2 pipeline. Suggest if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: In order to understand why your two Pcollections are not merging properly, could you provide some sample data for the ***p1 collection***? I have created a sample code to explain how CoGroupByKey works, [here](https://github.com/alemoraescarv/DataFlow/blob/master/CoGroupByKey_batch.py). As you can see, the merging is done based on the primary key (element[1]) of each Pcollection, which is 'Hello', 'Hello_world' and so on. What is the key you are using to merge? Did the code I created helped you?

Comment: this example works fine probably something to do with window. not sure though.

Comment: Could you provide sample data for p1?

Comment: generated this by printing the P1.
```('Hello_world', '2021-07-19 12:08:00')
('Hello_everyone', '2021-07-19 12:08:00')
('Hello', '2021-07-19 12:08:00')```

Comment: Is this second list(p2) fixed ? In other words, will you always add `'schdedule': ['sh 1','sh 1.1']` when the key is `Hello`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so just to contribute here.
The real purpose of this question is to join the data from dimension table or static data storage with the streaming data.
it is apparent from the question that **CoGroupByKey** doesn't join the time windowed and global windowed data. what is windowed and global windowed data?

**windowed** : in other terms a data group having windowed applied. which in turns applies the time boundaries over the constantly streaming data. therefore the number of rows can never be infinity.

**global windowed** : having no time stamp boundaries. it may be streaming or batch or a dimension table or a static data storage.

so we were having a conflict here because we were combining the windowed data with global windowed data.

**so how to resolve this case?**

there are different methods to do this. few of them are listed below.

**1.** make both the data stream into same window.

**2.** using sideinputs. read [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs-windowing). more info [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/)

**3.** using setup method in Pardo transformation.

in my case I sought there is no requirement to generate a window for static data therefore I implemented this using solution **2** and **3**.

**solution2**

```
def run(input_topic,input_subscription, output_path, window_size=1.0, num_shards=5, pipeline_args=None):
    # Set `save_main_session` to True so DoFns can access globally imported modules.
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )
#     pipeline = Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        p1 =  pipeline | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)\
                 | "Window into" >> GroupMessagesByFixedWindows(window_size, num_shards)\
                 |"adding time stamp value ">> Map(lambda x : (x[0],datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(x[1])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))\
                 |"p1 group by">>GroupByKey()

        p2 = pipeline |"generating data">> Create([('Hello','sh 1'),('Hello','sh 1.1'),
        ('Hello_world','sh 2'),
        ('Hello_everyone','sh 3'),
        ('Hello_cloud','sh 4')])\
         |"p2 group by">> GroupByKey()      
        p1|"perfomring join">> Map(join_data,beam.pvalue.AsDict(p2))| Map(print)
```

**solution3**

```
class join_data(DoFn):
    def setup(self):
        self.sample_data_dict = {'Hello':['sh 1','sh 1.1'],
    'Hello_world':'sh 2',
    'Hello_everyone':'sh 3',
    'Hello_cloud':'sh 4'}
        return
    def process(self,ele):
        yield ((ele[0],ele[1],self.sample_data_dict[ele[0]]))

def run(input_topic,input_subscription, output_path, window_size=1.0, num_shards=5, pipeline_args=None):
    # Set `save_main_session` to True so DoFns can access globally imported modules.
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )
#     pipeline = Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        p1 =  pipeline | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)\
                 | "Window into" >> GroupMessagesByFixedWindows(window_size, num_shards)\
|"adding time stamp value ">> Map(lambda x : (x[0],datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(x[1])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))\
|"p1 group by">>GroupByKey()
        p1|"perfomring transformation">> ParDo(join_data())| Map(print)
```

In production pipeline, we might encounter this problem to transform streaming data by adding dimension information in it we can easily utilise **setup** and **start_bundle** to create a database/bigquery connection.
please note : **setup method is called once per class instance/per worker** and **start_bundle method is called per window or per group of rows**. [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.31.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.start_bundle). more info on ParDo [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/).

in both the cases I was able to get the desired results mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

In order to further contribuite to the community, I am posting this answer.

I am assuming your second PCollection, **p2**, is fixed and immutable. So for every new record from **p1**, it will be merged with the appropriate key from **p2**. In other words, every time that a record has `Hello` as primary key, `schdedule': ['sh 1','sh 1.1']` will be added to the final output.

As mentioned in the comments, the method [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/cogroupbykey/) works without the windowing function. As in the example below,

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import Create, Map, ParDo, Flatten
from apache_beam import CoGroupByKey
from apache_beam import pvalue, window, WindowInto

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    
    timestamps= [('Hello','2021-07-16 13:19:00'),('Hello_world','2021-07-16 13:19:00'),('Hello_everyone','2021-07-16 13:19:00'),
                 ('Hello_cloud','2021-07-16 13:19:00')]
    p1 = pipeline | "Timestamps" >> Create(timestamps)
    
        #creating sample data 
    p2 = pipeline | "creating a sample data" >> Create([('Hello','sh 1'),('Hello','sh 1.1'),
    ('Hello_world','sh 2'),
    ('Hello_everyone','sh 3'),
    ('Hello_cloud','sh 4')])
    
    ({"schdedule":p2,"timestamp":p1}) | "merging" >> CoGroupByKey() | "merge print">> Map(print)
```

However, when windowing the first PCollection, **p1**, the second PCollection is not merged. This happens because the second PCollection is not windowed, the elements do not have a timestamp in order to be put in the same window(or not) as **p1**. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/),

> **Side inputs and windowing**
>
> Beam uses the window(s) for the main input element to look up the
> appropriate window for the side input element. Beam projects the main
> input element’s window into the side input’s window set, and then uses
> the side input from the resulting window. If the main input and side
> inputs have identical windows, the projection provides the exact
> corresponding window. However, if the inputs have different windows,
> Beam uses the projection to choose the most appropriate side input
> window.

In your case, **p2** is not in the same window as **p1**, since it does not have a timestamp. So it is not present in the output. However, there is a workaround. Considering that **p2** is immutable, as previously said, we can:

1. First convert the p1's timestamps to UNIX
2. Merge the **p2** to **p1**
3. Window the output based on p1's timestamps

A simplified version of this code using a batch model for simplicity is,

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import Create, Map, 
from apache_beam import  CoGroupByKey
from apache_beam import pvalue, window, WindowInto

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    
    timestamps= [('Hello','2021-07-16 13:19:00'), ('Hello','2021-07-16 13:19:05'),('Hello_world','2021-07-16 13:19:00'),('Hello_everyone','2021-07-16 13:19:00'),
                 ('Hello_cloud','2021-07-16 13:19:00')]
    p1 = pipeline | "Timestamps" >> Create(timestamps) | "Add timestamps" >> Map(lambda x: window.TimestampedValue(x, date2unix(x[1])))
    
        #creating sample data 
    p2 = (pipeline | "creating a sample data" >> Create([('Hello','sh 1'),('Hello','sh 1.1'),
    ('Hello_world','sh 2'),
    ('Hello_everyone','sh 3'),
    ('Hello_cloud','sh 4')]))
    
    (({"schdedule":p2,"timestamp":p1}) | "merging" >> CoGroupByKey() 
                                       | "FixedWindow2" >> WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60)) #60 seconds windows
                                       | "merge print">> Map(print))
```

And the output,

```
('Hello', {'schdedule': ['sh 1', 'sh 1.1'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00', '2021-07-16 13:19:05']})
('Hello_world', {'schdedule': ['sh 2'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
('Hello_everyone', {'schdedule': ['sh 3'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
('Hello_cloud', {'schdedule': ['sh 4'], 'timestamp': ['2021-07-16 13:19:00']})
```

Notice that for the key `Hello` there are two timestamps within the same window, which confirms that windowing was used properly.

Comment: once it groups the timestamps with global window, how will it be able to window it into 1 minute ? I tried this and it is yielding me no result.

Comment: You are somewhere clos to this ... I achieved this with SideInputs. please refer the answer I will be posting in a while.

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance and your time. keep contributing.

Comment: Thanks, please I would appreciate if you can update the answer if you found the information useful.